# Is there a way to make google charts repond to extent of map in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, jquery, carto-js, chart

I have figure out how to make a google chart responsive to a click event (view sample code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ohasselblad/33e5f5f6c72f2ec45e87)) and also responsive in an infowindow (view sample code [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/infowindow_with_graph.html)) but is there a way to make it respond based on the extent of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for sure.

Leaflet has a method called `getBounds()` that finds the bounding coordinates of the current map view. You can use this with the [CartoDB SQL API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#getting-data-with-sql) with CartoDB.js to do a custom query based on the view.

```
$('#getTotal').on('click',function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    console.log(bounds);
    sql.execute("SELECT SUM(pop_min) pmin_total,SUM(pop_max) pmax_total FROM ne_10m_populated_places_simple_1 WHERE ST_Intersects(the_geom, ST_Envelope(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(" + bounds._southWest.lng + " " + bounds._southWest.lat + ", " + bounds._northEast.lng + " " + bounds._northEast.lat + ")')))")
      .done(function(data) {
          draw_chart([+data.rows[0].pmin_total, +data.rows[0].pmax_total], "Totals for current view");
          console.log(data); 
      });
});
```

In this example, I created a button that triggers the calculation of the bounds of the current view, inserts those values into a SQL string that is then executed. The SELECT statement has the sum of the populations (max,min) of all the populated places within the boundary. Once that query is successful it returns the values in the `data` object, which can then be passed to a function to draw the charts.

The SQL part is the key here. It only returns points that are within the envelope,  sums of the specified values for those points, and then returns the summed value as the total population within the given view.

See the working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ohasselblad/d9b65186664268d6dec4).